Full methodological and theoretical description of the X-13-ARIMA-SEATS model
I've been trying to learn about the theory and methodology of the X-13-ARIMA-SEATS model used for seasonal adjustments. All that seems to be available are software implementations and manuals for such softwares.
Is there any source available that describes the theory of the X-13-ARIMA-SEATS model?

The standard reference is Dagum, E. B., & Bianconcini, S. (2016). Seasonal adjustment methods and real time trend-cycle estimation. Springer. Amazon

Thanks, I hadn't seen this! Although it explains mainly X12 and seems to suggest that X13 can be built from X12 and SEATS models. But not sure if it contains X13 explicitly.
